# Point a pointer to local variable created within a function

Tags: multithreading, go, pointers, slice, goroutine

Here is the code:

```
var timePointer *[]time.Time

func UpdateHolidayList() error {
    //updating logic: pulling list of holidays from API
    
    holidaySlice := make([]time.Time, 0)

    //appending some holidays of type time.Time to holidaySlice
    //now holidaySlice contains a few time.Time values

    timePointer = &holidaySlice

    return nil
}

func main() {

//run UpdateHoliday every 7 days
    go func() {
        for {
            UpdateHoliday()
            time.Sleep(7 * 3600 * time.Hour)
        }
    }()

}
```

I have 4 questions:

1. `holidaySlice` is a local variable, is it safe to point a (global) pointer to it?
2. Is this whole code multi-thread safe?
3. After pointing `timePointer` to `holidaySlice`, can I access the values via `timePointer`
4. (If answer to 3. is "yes") The holiday list is constantly changing, so `holidaySlice` will be different each update. Will the values accessed via `timePointer` change accordingly then?

Answer (score 0):

`holidaySlice` is a local variable allocated on the heap. Any variable pointing to the same heap location can access the data structure at that location. Whether or not it is safe depends on how you access it. Even if `holidaySlice` was not explicitly allocated on the heap, once you make a global variable point to it, Go compiler would detect that it "escapes", so it would allocate that on the heap.

The code is not thread-safe. You are modifying a shared variable (the global variable) without any explicit synchronization, so there is no guarantee on when or if other goroutines will see the updates to that variable.

If you update the contents of the `timePointer` array without explicit synchronization, there is no guarantee on when or if other goroutines will see those updates. You have to use synchronization primitives like `sync/Mutex` to delimit read/write access to data structures that can be updated/read by multiple goroutines.

Answer (score 0):

1. As long as your main does not end `timePointer` will have access to the pointer that `holidaySlice` creates - since its heap allocated, compiler will detect its escape and not free the memory.
2. Nope, absolutely not. Look at the [sync](https://pkg.go.dev/sync) package
3. Yes you can. Just remember to iterate using `*timePointer` instead of `timePointer`
4. It will change - but not accordingly. Since you have not done any synchronization - you have no defined way of knowing what data is stored at slice pointed to by `timePointer` when it is read.